# How compute $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(t+n)^2t^2}{[1+(t+n)^2]^3} dt ?$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Put $$I_n= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{(t+n)^2t^2}{[1+(t+n)^2]^3} dt \ (n\in \mathbb N).$$  We note that for each fixed $n\in \mathbb N, $ $I_n$ is convergent.

[ For $t\geq 1, \frac{(t+n)^2t^2}{[1+(t+n)^2]^3} \leq \frac{1}{1+t^2}$, therefor  $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{(t+n)^2t^2}{[1+(t+n)^2]^3} dt $ is convergent  by comparison test, and near near origin no singularity. So, $I_n$ is convergent for each fixed $n$.  ]

> Question: Can  we compute $I_n$? Is $\{I_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$  a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 3):

$$ I_n = \int_0^\infty \frac{(t+n)^2t^2}{[1+(t+n)^2]^3} dt $$
$$ I_n = \int_0^\infty \frac{n^2+2nt+1}{(n^2+2nt+t^2+1)^3} + \frac{-n^2-2nt-2}{(n^2+2nt+t^2+1)^2} + \frac{1}{n^2+2nt+t^2+1} \, dt$$

using partial fraction expansion and from here you can integrate using $u$-substitutions to find

$$ I_n = \left[\frac{1}{8} \left( (n^2+3)\arctan(n+t) + \frac{n^3+n^2t+3n-5t}{n^2+2nt+t^2+1} - \frac{2(n^3 + n^2t + n -t) }{(n^2+2nt+t^2+1)^2} \right)\right]_{t=0}^{t=\infty}$$

take the limit as $t\to \infty$ and,

$$ I_n = \frac{\pi}{16}(n^2+3) - \frac{1}{8}(n^2+3)\arctan(n) - 
\frac{n}{8} $$

and $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim} I_n = 0$ and let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \,n \mapsto \frac{\pi}{16}(n^2+3) - \frac{1}{8}(n^2+3)\arctan(n) - 
\frac{n}{8}$,

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial n} = \frac{-(n^2+3)}{8(n^2+1)} + \frac{\pi n}{8} - \frac{n\arctan(n)}{4} - \frac{1}{8} < 0 \quad\forall n$$

So since $I_n = f \, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n} < 0$, and $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim} I_n = 0$ then $I_n$ has a lower bound of $y=0$.

In addition $ \underset{n\to -\infty}{\lim} I_n \to \infty $, so $I_n$ has no upper bound.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me which substitutions I should perform to reach 3rd step? eg. how the first integral is $\frac{1}{8} (n^2+3) \arctan( n+t)$, ...?

Comment: @abcd for the third factor ($1$ in numerator) you can complete the square in the denominator factor out $\frac{1}{(n^2+1)-n^2}$ and substitute $u\mapsto n+t$ to arrive a $\arctan(n+t)$

Comment: @abcd for middle factor I split that into $-\frac{-4n^2-2(-n^2-2)}{2(n^2+2nt+t^2+1)^2} - \frac{n(2n+2t)}{(n^2+2nt+t^2+1)^2}$ and from that you can factor out a $-n$ and an $(n^2-2)$ respectively. Then make the substitution $u\mapsto (n^2+2nt+t^2+1)$ for the first fraction and for the second, complete the square in the denominator and substitute $v\mapsto n+t$ and then simplify and then again substitute $p \mapsto \arctan(v)$ to arrive at $\frac{1}{2}\left( (n^2-2)\arctan(n+t) + \frac{n^3+n^2t-2t}{n^2+2nt+t^2+1}\right)$

Comment: @D: $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{n^2+ 2nt +1} {(n^2+2nt+t^2+1)^3} dt = \frac{1}{8} (n^3+3) \arctan (n+t)$? Thanks

Comment: @abcd the first fraction actually comes out to $\frac{1}{8}\left( -\frac{3(n^2-1)(n+t)}{n^2+2nt+t^2+1}-3(n^2-1)\arctan(n+t)-\frac{2(n^3+n^2t+n-t)}{(n^2+2nt+t^2+1)^2} \right)$. I got to this by splitting the first fraction, taking out $(1-n^2)$ constant, substitute $u\mapsto n^2+2nt+t^2+1$ and then completing the square. This one is rather messy, but then once you're done combine it with the other results and you get the result shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some place to start.

You can convert to partial fraction. After some work, you should get someting like
$$
{\frac { \left( t+n \right) ^{2}{t}^{2}}{ \left( 1+ \left( t+n
 \right) ^{2} \right) ^{3}}}={\frac {-{n}^{2}-2-2\,tn}{ \left( 1+{t}^{
2}+2\,tn+{n}^{2} \right) ^{2}}}+ \left( 1+{t}^{2}+2\,tn+{n}^{2}
 \right) ^{-1}+{\frac {1+{n}^{2}+2\,tn}{ \left( 1+{t}^{2}+2\,tn+{n}^{2
} \right) ^{3}}}.
$$

Each of those can be integrated using standard techniques, like trig subs, u-subs, completing the square, etc.

This gives 
\begin{align*}
\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac { \left( t+n \right) ^{2}{t}^{2}}{ \left( 
1+ \left( t+n \right) ^{2} \right) ^{3}}}{dt}&=-1/8\,\arctan \left( n
 \right) {n}^{2}-1/8\,n-3/8\,\arctan \left( n \right) +3/16\,\pi +1/16
\,\pi \,{n}^{2}\\
&=  \left( -1/8\,\arctan \left( n \right) +1/16\,\pi  \right) {n}^{2}-1/8
\,n-3/8\,\arctan \left( n \right) +3/16\,\pi
\end{align*}

Now this appears to be decreasing, has limit $0$ and thus is bounded. I'm lacking time to complete.